# Modifying Pandas DataFrame column names using a function

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to create a function that I can apply to each of my DataFrames to clean up the column names.

For example:

```
def standardize_headers(df):
     return df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_').str.lower()
```

However, when I apply it using the code:

```
df2 = df.apply(standardize_headers)
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'", u'occurred at index External_Code')
```

'External_Code' is the first column in df. I know I could do this simple example as a lambda function, but I plan to have a more complicated function with multiple steps so I will need to be able to reference column names in a user defined function. I know apply treats the object as a series. So how can I refer to columns within a user defined functions? Or maybe the issue is with the way I'm applying the function to the DataFrame.

Comment: Can you add the sample of  `df`. So we can reproduce the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
def standardize_headers(df, func=None):
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_').str.lower()
    if func:
      df = df.apply(func)
    return df

df2 = standardize_headers(df)
```

You can expand on this template to either simply return a renamed DataFrame, or to pass multiple functions to apply to the DataFrame before returning it.

Comment: This works and also works with my more complicated function. Thanks

Comment: Downvoted. There is an idiomatic way to change column names and it's with the `rename` method which can be passed a function to do any complex renaming.

Comment: @TedPetrou, sure, `rename` works in this case, (the main benefit being `inplace` assignment), but that's more of a detail and not the fundamental question -- read the last paragraph. OP asked for a way to change column names inside a function before using the renamed columns in subsequent DF operations.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this would be with the `rename` method. You can pass the `columns` parameter a function and this function will be applied to each column name. Notice that the `x` in the function is a string so you may directly use string methods.

```
def standardize_headers(x):
    return x.replace(' ', '_').lower()

df.rename(columns=standardize_headers)
```

The apply function works directly with the values in each column as a Series.

Comment: In the question, I stated that this worked as a lambda function. But I needed it to be a user defined function because I wanted to make it more complex

Comment: Just make it a user defined function. The other answer is not very good.

Comment: You're going to want to add `inplace=True` or assign back to `df`.

Comment: @TedPetrou, you're failing to read the entire question. I need to be able to reference column names. There will be things I need to apply to each column that isn't as simple as a rename. Yes you're code solves the example I provided.